# Как в html datalist убрать не нужные поля?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, datalist

Обновляю datalist через ajax, но сохраняются другие значения, на картинке это 4,1,2. Как удалять их?

удаляю все option предыдущие так
`document.getElementById('one_form-device').innerHTML = '';`

**html**

```
<input id="ajax_input_one_form-device" list="one_form-device" name="one_form-device" value="" required="" placeholder="Loading options...">
<datalist id="one_form-device">
<option value="3">Casio</option>
<option value="5">Casio Edifice</option>
<option value="6">Casio G-Shock</option>
</datalist>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уберите бесполезный скрин и добавьте воспроизводимый пример

Comment: проблему решил, добавил в input autocomplete="off"

Answer (score 0):

У всех наследников `HTMLElement` есть метод `remove` (доставшийся от `ChildNode`, но это уже не суть важно).
Следовательно, для удаления ненужных option'ов - остается лишь немножко задействовать мозг, для формализации критерия ненужности в ветвлении алгоритма.

Например, если представить что ненужными являются только те элементы option, у которых ровно один символ в их текстовом содержимом:

```js
const datalist = document.querySelector('#one_form-device');
for (const option of [...datalist.options]) {
  if (option.textContent.length === 1)
    option.remove();
}
```

```html
<input id="ajax_input_one_form-device" list="one_form-device" name="one_form-device" value="" required="" placeholder="Loading options...">
<datalist id="one_form-device">
  <option value="3">Casio</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">Casio Edifice</option>
  <option value="6">Casio G-Shock</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
</datalist>
```